# Encrypted code from OpenSSL C++ doesnt produce right output when decrypt from online des encryption tools

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, des

I have a simple C++ application where I want to encrypt some text using openssl DES. here's the snippet of what I am doing.

```
DES_cblock Key1 = { '@','2','&','%','$','H' ,'^', '6' };
DES_key_schedule SchKey1;
DES_cblock input_data = { 'M', 'y', 'S', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e' };
/* Print Encrypted and Decrypted data packets */
void print_data(const char* tittle, const void* data, int len);

int main()
{   
if (-2 == DES_set_key_checked(&Key1, &SchKey1) || -2 == DES_set_key_checked(&Key2, &SchKey2) || -2 == DES_set_key_checked(&Key3, &SchKey3))
{
    printf(" Weak key ....\n");
    return 1;
}

/* Buffers for Encryption and Decryption */
DES_cblock cipher;
DES_cblock text;
DES_set_odd_parity(&Key1);

DES_ecb_encrypt(&input_data, &cipher, &SchKey1, DES_ENCRYPT);

DES_ecb_encrypt(&cipher, &text, &SchKey1, DES_DECRYPT);

print_data("\n Original ", (const void*)input_data, sizeof(input_data));
print_data("\n Encrypted", (const void*)cipher, sizeof(cipher));
print_data("\n Decrypted", (const void*)text, sizeof(text));

return 0;
}
```

print_data function is just printing the output in base64. here's the implementation:

```
void print_data(const char* title, const void* data, int len)
{
printf("%s : ", title);
const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)data;
string output = base64_encode(p, len);
cout << "Output | " << title << ": " << output << endl;
}
```

I am running this on windows visual studio. When I encrypt it the output is as follows(base64):

```
Encrypted: tC2/TTVGLYo=
```

I have a C# application where I am encrypting the same text with the same key in ECB mode. the output of C# matches exactly with DES online encryption tools but OPENSSL output neither matches C# nor with any online tool.
Basically, I have this scenario where I'll be encrypting C# decrypted data in C++ and vice versa.

Kindly give me some pointers. what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**:
Here's the encrypt function of C#(using same key and text as of C++):

```
 public static void Encrypt(string TextToEncrypt)
    {
        byte[] MyEncryptedArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextToEncrypt);
        byte[] MysecurityKeyArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mysecurityKey);

        var MyDESCryptoService = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        MyDESCryptoService.Key = MysecurityKeyArray;

        MyDESCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        MyDESCryptoService.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        var MyCrytpoTransform = MyDESCryptoService.CreateEncryptor();

        byte[] MyresultArray = MyCrytpoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(MyEncryptedArray, 0, MyEncryptedArray.Length);

        MyDESCryptoService.Clear();
        string SimpleEncrypted = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MyresultArray);
        Console.WriteLine("01 >>>" + SimpleEncrypted);
        String Base64Encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(MyresultArray, 0, MyresultArray.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("64 >>>" + Base64Encrypted);

        Console.WriteLine(Decrypt(Base64Encrypted));




    }
```

Comment: The `DES_set_odd_parity()` call must of course be made before the `DES_set_key_checked()` call.

Comment: Can you provide C# code as well

Comment: @idris I have edited my question and added c# encryption method as well.

Comment: @Topaco Your suggestion solved my issue. Thanks alot